# OFBiz + Hibernate? OFBiz + JSP?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, ofbiz

Would love some guidance on two things.

1. I'm considering building out a commerce site using JSPs as the front-end (and a very lightweight MVC framework I use frequently and which suits my needs perfectly for presentation), but with OFBiz as the commerce engine.  Two possible problems here:

   A. JSP front-ends look to be deprecated for the latest version of OFBiz

   B. if I ignore the fact that JSPs are deprecated in OFBiz, the question remains as to whether I can use my beloved MVC/JSP framework with the front-end components supplied by OFBiz.  (Note that this only applies to the public-facing part of the relatively simple -- but multi-language/multi-currency -- commerce site I'm building; I'd gladly use the admin screens provided by OFBiz, quite possibly out of the box.)
2. I'm also quite happy with Hibernate as the framework through which I access my data.  Unclear to me whether I can stick, 100%, with Hibernate and use OFBiz at the same time (or if I can't, how that integration would look).  What if I want to, say, handle user-account management (or user-generated content, or whatever) in a non-OFBiz way, but use OFBiz for anything commerce-related?  What about session persistence (in a clustered Tomcat environment)?

I should note that as far as front-end goes, I may end up using OFBiz only minimally (for stuff that truly nobody wants to reinvent the wheel for: calculating shipping; handling multiple currencies; dealing with sales tax/VAT/whatever for different U.S. states and different countries; etc.).  I'm comfortable writing my own product-search pages; product-detail pages; shopping-cart pages; even checkout pages (but there, I'd need, minimally, the backend help of OFBiz to provide me with sales-tax info, shipping-charge logic, and so on).

Perhaps the solution is to forget about OFBiz for the public site at all -- just use it for all the backend stuff and for its extensive admin screens; that's something I could also be comfortable with.  But I don't know how easy it is to use just portions of OFBiz.

A lot of questions here; apologies if this has been asked and answered before, but I've scoured this site and haven't found answers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with using OFBiz along with Hibernate there's a fork of the OFBiz project called Opentaps that has included Hibernate into the framework. You're able to access your data via Hibernate or the pre-existing Entity Engine in OFBiz

http://www.opentaps.org/

On top of all this, you may find it includes or extends to make it easier to get up and running with what you're trying to accomplish.

It has a pretty solid community.